# How to use AUTH_USER_MODEL if I just want to use the standard user model

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-auth-models

I have seen several posts and [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) about how it's best practice to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py, but do not see any actual examples on how to do that. I have tried several configurations but keep getting this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed

It doesn't even tell me where the error is occurring. Below are the methods I have tried:

**METHOD 1:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Then I would just reference my user like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Neither worked, and I'm not sure how I would set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py **if I just want to use the standard user model**. I'm not customizing the User object at all. I assume something like `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'` but I'm not sure.

Now I'm getting this:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

**users/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230321/discussion-on-question-by-tom-django-how-to-use-auth-user-model).

Answer (score 4):

> I assume something like `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'` but i'm not sure.

You refer to a model with `app_name.ModelName`, so in this case that is:

```
# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

This is also the *default* value, so if you want to work with Django's user model, you can simply omit the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in the `settings.py`.

furthermore you need to add `django.contrib.auth` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, so:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # …,
]
```

In a `ModelForm`, `ModelSerializer`, etc. you work with `get_user_model()` to get a reference to the user model class:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

Comment: I just updated my question. You helped me get the answer, so thank you! Any idea why it is now saying my SECRET_KEY is missing?

Comment: I am still having this issue. I will pay you $50 /hour to help me figure this out, I feel like we were close to solving it. For updated details I made this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791148/auth-user-model-error-in-production-only-auth-user-model-refers-to-model-auth

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Willem in his case. If you are going to keep this, I recommend the following.

In your Method1,

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

and then in views.py, use `get_user_model()` instead of `User`.
I hope it will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this.

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete=models.DO_WhatEver_You_Want)
```

Comment: The documentation explicitly says that this is not a good idea: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model The reason that this often is a problem is that if you later change the user model, it will take some time to alter all `ForeignKey`s/`OneToOneField`s.