# AUTH_USER_MODEL error in production only: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have my app working on localhost but when i deploy to production (**Heroku**), I get this error:

```
File "./blog/models.py", line 6, in <module>
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696194+00:00 app[web.1]: User = get_user_model()
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 162, in get_user_model
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696372+00:00 app[web.1]: "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696397+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

I have tried countless configurations, such as setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` in settings after doing `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

but nothing works.

**settings.py**

```
"""~~~NOTES~~~
- procfile could use channel_layer instead of channels
- AUTH_USER_MODEL could be 'django_project.User'. Worked locally but not on heroku
- django.setup() seems ok at bottom of settings.py
- If have to

"""

import django
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User #todo: this causes ImproperlyConfigured: SECRET_KEY MUST NOT BE EMPTY

import os
import django_heroku

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'django_project.settings'
SECRET_KEY = 'asdaf123$9pv98=e6p^gl(-eoj' #todo: test removing this in own deployment
# AUTH_USER_MODEL=User # todo: this causes RuntimeError: populate() isnt reentrant
#SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = 'True'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig', #allows Django to correctly search your templates for the 'blog' app
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    # 'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'chat',
    'crispy_forms',
    'channels',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django_messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # 'libraries': {
            #     'staticfiles':'chat.templatetags.__init__.py'
            # }
        },
    },
]

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) ,'../templates').replace('\\','/')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( # deprecated
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'blog/templates'), # Django will look at the templates from templates/ directory under your project
)

# ~~~MESSAGES CONFIG~~~
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.asgi.application' # older version of django: 'django_project.routing.application'

# Channels redis config:
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            #"hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)], or 'redis' #l ocal
            "hosts": ['rediss://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25180'], # REDIS_TLS_URL #todo: confirm. Changed from "127.0.0.1" to 'redis'... found promising answer, changing this
            # 'redis://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25179' REDIS_URL
        },
        # "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns", #todo: add "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns",
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL'),
         "OPTIONS": {
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {
                "ssl_cert_reqs": False
            }
        }
    }
}


DATABASES = { # Use this to use local test DB
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DB_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DATABASE_URL = DB_URL


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 4000
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfilescustom') #todo: may have to add own staticFileDir folder
]

django.setup()
```

**blog/models (which is where the error is complaining about):**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings



from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# we're inheriting from the models.Model
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # character field
    content = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()  # Unrestricted text
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # character field
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name_and_platform = models.TextField(default='N/A') #todo: find a good max char limit
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  # return game name when game.objects.all() is called

    def get_name_and_platform(self):
        return ''.join([self.name, '(', self.platform, ')'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_and_platform = self.get_name_and_platform()
        super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)




class Trade(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_trade_proposed = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    user_who_posted = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owned_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owned_game', db_column='owned_game')
    desired_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='desired_game', db_column='desired_game')

    def get_trade_name(self):
        return ''.join([self.user_who_posted.username, '(', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ')'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.get_trade_name()
        super(Trade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return game name when game.objects.all() is called


class Transaction(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    trade_one = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trade_one', db_column='trade_one')
    trade_two = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trade_two', db_column='trade_two')
    status = models.TextField()  # Unrestricted text. Validated in form.
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3))
    open_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=9))
    user_cancelled_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_transaction_name(self):
        return ''.join([str(self.trade_one_id), ' and ', str(self.trade_two_id), ' on ', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ''])

    def get_status_on_insert(self):
        return 'Waiting for 2nd confirmation from ' + str(self.trade_two.user_who_posted)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.name == '':
            self.name  = self.get_transaction_name()
        if self.status == '':
            self.status = self.get_status_on_insert()
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return name when game.objects.all() is called

    def get_absolute_url(self): #todo: remove?
        return reverse('confirmed-trade', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**chat/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
# from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone


class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) #todo: timezone fix?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

    def last_10_messages(self):
        return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10] # only load last x msgs from DB
```

**users/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**chat/consumers.py**

```
# chat/consumers.py
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Message


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def fetch_messages(self, data):
        print('~~~fetch_messages~~~')
        messages = Message.last_10_messages(self)
        content = {
            'command': 'messages',
            'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
        }
        print('content: ' + str(content))
        self.send_message(content)


    def new_message(self, data):
        print('~~~in new_message: 2~~~')
        author = data['from']
        print('author: ' + author)
        author_user = User.objects.filter(username=author)[0]
        message = Message.objects.create(author=author_user, content=data['message'])
        content = {
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': self.message_to_json(message)
        }
        return self.send_chat_message(content)


    def messages_to_json(self, messages):
        print('~~~messages_to_json~~~')
        result = []

        for message in messages:
            result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
        return result


    def message_to_json(self, message):
        print('~~~message_to_json~~~')
        return {
            'author': message.author.username,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }

    commands = {
        'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
        'new_message': new_message
    }


    def connect(self):
        print('~~~connect~~~')
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print('~~~disconnect~~~')
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        print('~~~receive: 1~~~')
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        self.commands[data['command']](self, data) # either fetch_messages or new_message

    def send_chat_message(self, message):
        print('in send_chat_message: 3')
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)( # Send message to room group
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):

        message = event['message']
        print('message: ' + str(message))
        content1 = message['message']
        print('content1: ' + str(content1))
        content2 = content1['content']
        print('content2: ' + content2)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message)) # Send message to WebSocket
```

**~~~~~~~~~UPDATE:~~~~~~~~~** When i switched my procfile from

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne django_project.asgi:application --port $PORST --bind 0.0.0.0 v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer --settings=django_project.settigns -v2
```

to

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

my application successfully built! Why would my procfile be resulting in that error?

Comment: Tried more configurations but still having the same issue. I do realize it's in blog/models.py, i am not importing the User model correctly in there

Comment: That error is caused if you replaced the Default User Model, did you customize the default User model in anyway?

Comment: Hi Mugoya, thanks for your help. That's the weird thing, I did not customize the default User model at all! I'm just trying to use the standard one

Comment: In blogs/models.py (where the error is), I do `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and then `User = get_user_model()` to get the default User model. Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, but if it is working on localhost then you delete all heroku migrations and then make migrate again maybe the User model was not created

Comment: Maybe i will try that, thank you! You mean delete all the migrations files (like `0001_initial.py`, ...)? Is that safe to do?

Comment: Yes you try that

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih I still got the same error after deleting all migration files, pushing the deletion to heroku, running `python3 manage.py makemigrations` then `python3 manage.py migrate`. After that, i pushed the new migration files to heroku and still got the same error

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih I have an important update: It looks like the Procfile is the source of the issue. Details in my Question

Comment: Wow am glad you found the cause to fix, it is always a pain debugging the code that runs perfectly on the local machine but fouls in production.

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih Thanks, but i did not fix the error. Im still getting the import error

Comment: That is the hustle of deploying django apps, but i believe you are on the right track, you will fix that importError

Comment: @Tom Did you resolve this?